# Delete entire row from SQLite android using two given column data

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, sql-delete

I want to delete a specific row in SQLITE data in android.Now, I already try only using only one column data like primary key  but now I want to delete an entire row using a column key and column name .How will I do this?help me

Below is the syntax I made to delete, but their nothing happen?
DatabaseHandler.java

```
public Cursor delete(String id, String name){

    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();
     String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM Criteria WHERE criteria_eventpk ="+"'"+id+"' AND criteria_eventpk ="+"'"+name+"'" ;
        Cursor idupdate = data.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        data.close();   
        return  idupdate;
```

I use rawQuery because I try db.delete but only one data is only allowed.So I try rawQuery .

Next, the codes in the button delete in my MainActivity

```
 evcri_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        db.delete(evpk.getText().toString(), cripk.getText().toString());   



        }
    });
```

I think I made a wrong choice to choose cursor, Can anyone help me?I guess a custom query is needed but I need your help.Help me..

I try this ,but still it doesn't work.In their any wrong code I use?

```
public void delete(Criteria cri, Criteria pk){
    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();
    data.delete(TABLE_CRITERIA,"criteria_name=? AND criteria_eventpk=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(cri.get_criname()),String.valueOf(pk.get_eventpk())});

    data.close();
```

---

In my delete button

```
    db.delete(evpk.getText().toString(), cripk.getText().toString());
```

But when I try this code below, it works but only the id is given,I want the given are id and name..

```
    data.delete(TABLE_CRITERIA,"criteria_name=?, new String[]{String.valueOf(cri.get_criname())});
```

Comment: I use rawQuery because I try db.delete **but only one data is only allowed.** <= ?????????????????? what is wrong with: `db.delete(tablename, "crit1=? and crit2=?", new String[] {crit1value, crit2value });`

Comment: @Selvin I added codes above, I try the one you suggest, but still it doesn'n work,
I really need the two given data in deleting a row.:( Help

Comment: It seems that you are getting the delete parameters from a TextEdit. In this case, you can have 2 issues: the text can have trailing spaces (you must use String.trim() to remove it), or the text entered can have capital characters that does not match with your database (are you using `collate nocase` in your table?).

Comment: I am not getting the textEdit, I am getting in TextView.Can you show me an example code using trim?pls..

Answer (score 2):

> I use rawQuery because I try db.delete but only one data is only allowed.So I try rawQuery .

This information is not correct. The db.delete method allows multiple parameters:

```
    public int delete(String id, String name){
        SQLiteDatabase data = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String table = "Criteria";
        String whereClause = "criteria_eventpk=? AND criteria_eventpk =?" ;
        String whereArgs[] = new String[] {id, name};

        int count = data.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
        data.close();

        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I put the single quotes inside the double quotes and it always works for me
      String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM Criteria WHERE criteria_eventpk ='"+id+"' AND criteria_eventpk ='"+name+"'" ;

Comment: I tried the codes you suggest, but still it doesn't work.
If its work for you,can you give me an example?that implies 2 data in deleting a row ?sample source code pls..

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is of the form:

```
DELETE FROM Criteria WHERE criteria_eventpk = /id/ AND criteria_eventpk = /name/
```

So criteria_eventpk has to equal both the value of id and the value of name. That will only be the case where id and name are the same which I imagine is not usually going to be the case?

Did you want to delete where criteria_eventpk is equal to either id or name? If so change the AND to OR. Or do you mean to check two different columns in the row? In which case one of the criteria_eventpk's needs changing.

Comment: @NigeIK I want to delete the row where criteria_pk is equal to id.getText and criteria_eventpk is equal to name.gettext.That's it.